# USB 3G Modem for embedded linux

Tags: usb, modem, 3g

I am fairly new to linux world, I have to develop an application on embedded linux which sends data over internet. I have to choose a USB 3G modem with a SIM card holder. I would appreciate if anyone can help me choosing a USB 3G modem which works successfully or is supported on embedded linux.

Thanks
Emby

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might also try posting your question on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I will wait and see if I get a response or else I will post my question on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: this question is off topic here.  I would like to know the answer, though... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Pantech modems with Debian ARM linux for real-time vessel tracking.

Linux can use the cdc_acm and ppp kernel modules to drive many of the USB modems on the market.  You may need to compile these modules depending on how stripped your embedded platform is.  Alternatively, you can use a turnkey system like a Raven or MultiTech, but they draw much more power.

Avoid USB modems that have additional hardware such as SD cards.  These modems require specialized drivers (many unavailable in open source) to peel away the non-modem hardware layers before exposing the actual modem.

Comment: Thanks, I have bought simple E220(Huawei) USB modem. It is supported by default on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Use a modem that is supported by ModemManager, an OpenSource project that is in many major Linux distro's, no need to reinvent the wheel!

Supported Modem:
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ModemManager/SupportedDevices/

Project Source:
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ModemManager/